# How to stub parent class method call in my mocked abstract class that I want to test using PowerMock

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-fragments, powermock

Here is my class structure

```
public abstract class MyTabFragment extends Fragment {


public void myMethod(final Parameter reason) {
    if (isAdded()) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
            if (getActionDelegateHandler() != null) {
                getActionDelegateHandler().handleThis(reason.getMessageId());
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "no action handler");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my test class. Basically I want to unit test myMethod() which has calls to its parent Fragment class' isAdded() and getActivity() calls. I want to stub out these method calls but I'm not able to.

```
@Test
public void testattempt() throws Exception {

    MyTabFragment testFragment = PowerMockito.mock(MyTabFragment.class);
    PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(testFragment).myMethod(any(Parameter.class));

    when(testFragment.isAdded()).thenReturn(true); //This line throws error
    when(testFragment.getActivity()).thenReturn(fragmentActivity);
    when(testFragment.getActionDelegateHandler()).thenReturn(null);
    doAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            Runnable runnable = (Runnable) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            runnable.run();
            return null;
        }
    }).when(fragmentActivity).runOnUiThread(any(Runnable.class));


    testFragment.myMethod(mockParameter);
    //asserts here...
    //verify(testFragment).getActionDelegateHandler();
}
```

Running the test throws error at the line where i'm mocking the isAdded() call.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
Or 'a static method call on a prepared class`
For example:
    @PrepareForTest( { StaticService.class }) 
    TestClass{
       public void testMethod(){
           PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticService.class);
           when(StaticService.say()).thenReturn(expected);
       }
    }

Also, this error might show up because:
1. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
2. inside when() you don't call static method, but class has not been prepared.
```

How do I resolve this. I'm using PowerMock. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found out that normal mock calls do actually work. The problem was that in my setup() method I had suppressed all super class' calls. After I mocked out the only super calls I needed to, for other tests, I was able to mock my expected methods as usual.